# Why is it so slow to add or remove elements in the middle of a vector?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, containers

According to Accelerated C++:

> To use this strategy, we need a way to remove an element from a vector. The good news is that such a facility exists; the bad news is that removing elements from vectors is slow enough to argue against using this approach for large amounts of input data. If the data we process get really big, performance degrades to an astonishing extent.
>
> For example, if all of our students were to fail, the execution time of the function that we are about to see would grow proportionally to the square of the number of students. That means that for a class of 100 students, the program would take 10,000 times as long to run as it would for one student. The problem is that our input records are stored in a vector, which is optimized for fast random access. One price of that optimization is that it can be expensive to insert or delete elements other than at the end of the vector.

The authors do not explain why the vector would be so slow for 10,000+ students, and why in general it is slow to add or remove elements to the middle of a vector. Could somebody on *Stack Overflow* come up with a beautiful answer for me?

Comment: AC++ is a good book that we recommend, so I seriously doubt they don't explain what vector is and isn't good for and why. Did you keep reading to find out?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Did you intend to remove the citation when you edited this?  The question is worse without it.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Accident; sorry and thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a row of houses: if you build them in a straight line, then finding No. 32 is really easy: just walk along the road about 32 houses' worth, and you're there. But it's not quite so fun to add house No. 31½ in the middle — that's a big construction project with a lot of disruption to husband's/wife's and kids' lives. In the worst case, there is not enough space on the road for another house anyway, so you have to move *all* the houses to a different street before you even start.

Similarly, vectors store their data *contiguously*, i.e. in a continuous, sequential block in memory.

This is very good for quickly finding the *n*<sup>th</sup> element (as you simply have to trundle along *n* positions and dereference), but very bad for inserting into the middle as you have to move all the later elements along by one, one at a time.

Other containers are designed to be easy to insert elements, but the trade-off is that they are consequently not quite as easy to find things in. There is no container which is optimal for all operations.

Comment: This is such a good answer in that it perfectly answered all my pondering.  I am sorry for picking the best answer so quickly, it's just that phenomenal :)  Thank you for helping me out, Stackoverflow!  Y'all are amazing.

Answer (score 2):

When inserting elements into or removing elements from the middle of a `std::vector<T>` all elements after the modification point need to moved: when inserting they need to be moved further to the back, when removing they need to be moved forward to close the gap. The background is that `std::vector<T>` is basically just a contiguous sequence of elements.

Although this operation isn't too bad for certain types it can become comparatively slow. Note, however, that the size of the container needs to be of some sensible size or the cost of moving be significant: for small vectors, inserting into/removing from the middle is probably faster than using other data structures, e.g., lists. Eventually the cost of maintaining a more complex structure does pay off, however.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector allocates memory as one extent. If you need to insert an element in the middle of the extend you have to shift right all elements of the vector that to make a free slot where you will nsert the new element. And moreover if the extend is already full of elements the vector need to allocate a new larger extend and copy all elements from the original extent to the new one.